# A user has multiplied!

Tags: support, chat, merge-accounts

I'm in chat (about a question) and I'm talking to a user. For some reason the chat insists that there are in fact two users:

[image]

Here are the two users [one](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2888561/bjb568) and [two](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2371861/bjb568) they have two different chat userids.

The first chat account link 404s and the second links to the correct user page on Stack Overflow.

This looks like a merge accounts bug.

Comment: Yup. And I complained to SE a while back and still no reply!

Comment: @bjb568 Is there a related question you asked ? Or did you contact them another way ?

Comment: @dystroy I gave them details thru the "contact us" link.

Comment: No wonder I received that message.  Appears that they flush messages received via "contact us" to `/dev/null`.

Comment: they have different reputations too....

Comment: There are two _chats_ in your chat!

Comment: I once had a Doppelganger. A user with my very same name (I was named Vyger, at those times) and my very same avatar (a crash test dummy profile head silhouette)! Then I changed my avatar a bit (modified the colors), to be recognizable to my "followers".

Comment: Are you sure they multiplied and didn't divide instead?

Comment: My accounts are sorta unmerged now, I poked Anna Lear. Still some borkage.

Comment: Yes, the agents sometimes show up in the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

> For some reason the chat insists that there are in fact two users

They were, in fact, two users, but the same person. This has been solved. You can check some of [the history](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=merge&Room=89&User=237813&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest) following the chat conversations with Anna Lear.